# Не получается Записать или Прочитать данные по COM порту pyqt 5 используя библиотеку qtserialport

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, com-port

Не получается ПрочитатЬ данные по COM порту между ноутбуками. Использую библиотеку qtserialport pyqt 5. Ошибок не возникает. Линия и порты исправны так как все получается если пользоваться специальной утилитой COM Port Toolkit 4.0. По отдельности пробовал читать тоже безрезультатно, но запись данных получается. Оказалась проблема была что нет waitForReadyRead для чтения данных. Пример ниже рабочий.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice, QBitArray
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Нажми кнопку для запуска потока")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.btnRead = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Чтение")
        self.btnWrite = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Запись")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnRead)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnWrite)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.btnRead.clicked.connect(self.Read_Buf)
        self.btnWrite.clicked.connect(self.Write_Buf)

        self.serport = QSerialPort()
        self.serport.setBaudRate(9600)
        self.serport.setPortName("COM3")
        self.serport.setDataBits(8)
        self.serport.setParity(0)
        self.serport.setStopBits(1)
        print(self.serport.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite))
        print(self.serport.isReadable())


    def Read_Buf(self):
        strBuf = QBitArray()
        strBuf.resize(100)

        while self.serport.waitForReadyRead(100) == 0:
            count = 1
            strBuf = self.serport.readLine(7)
            print(str(strBuf))
            print(count)
            if len(strBuf) > 0:
                break
            time.sleep(1)


    def Write_Buf(self):
        count = 2
        self.serport.write(b'1111')
        print(count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Запуск и остановка потока")
    window.resize(300,100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: HET,  нельзя использовать в основном потоке ни `while True:` ни `time.sleep(1)` - это блокирует GUI. Почитайте о -  Класс QTimer предоставляет повторяющиеся и одиночные таймеры.https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

Comment: Сигналы и слоты используются для связи между объектами. Механизм сигналов и слотов является центральной особенностью Qt и, вероятно, той частью, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими платформами. Сигналы и слоты становятся возможными благодаря мета-объектной системе Qt.

Вам надо крепко изучить https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html и https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html

Comment: Понимаю что нельзя, но я данные не могу принять и отправить именно из-за этого?

Comment: @S.Nick Вот исправил на потоки и слоты. Сообщения не приходят , но готовность порта есть и интерфейс не выводится.

Comment: Потоки не запускаются вызовом `self.thread.run()` надо `self.thread.start()`. Кнопки тоже не соединены своими кликами ни с чем.

Comment: поправил то что вы написали. Кнопки просто для дальнейшей проверки работы потока, пока до этого не дошел. Хоть и заработал интерфейс , но все равно не работает передача данных.

Comment: я вам предложу полистать посты https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+QtSerialPort , надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Серийник вы открываете в одном потоке self.serport.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite), а потом перекидываете его в другой - так работать не будет. Но в целом, я вам рекомендую отказаться от использования серийника в потоках - в этом нет никакого смысла - они асинхронные. Почитайте вот это (там ответ от разработчика этого модуля)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559610/how-to-setup-qserialport-on-a-separate-thread

Если проблема будет с открытием порта, то можно воспользоваться таймером.

Comment: @Alexander Chernin я делал без потока , но S. Nick сказал что нужно использовать потоки и слоты. Не понимаю кто прав и что делать. Так и так не работает. Исправил пример свой без потока.

Comment: @JIoBuboJIT я такого вам НЕ говорил. Во-первых в предыдущем вопросе я отослал вас на ссылку, которая рекомендовала не использовать потоки. Во-вторых я вам писал, что вам надо изучить СИГНАЛЫ и СЛОТЫ

Comment: @S. Nick да по ссылки понял что можно не использовать потоки и слоты (комментарий писал).  Для данной задачи нужно будет в дальнейшем перейти на потоки и слоты. В данный момент у меня получилось передать данные , но получить данные по COM  порту не получается даже в таком случае, значит как то неправильно получаю и слоты делать пытаться дальше нет смысла пока не разберусь с этим.

Comment: @S. Nick все получилось. Оказывается надо использовать QSerialPort::waitForReadyRead() ждем байты и потом читаем с порта :) .Какая то одна команда все решила. Столько времени мучался. Спасибо всем за советы! Продолжу дальше свой проект.

Comment: @JIoBuboJIT  да,  одна команда может решить все. Удачи вам.

Comment: @JIoBuboJIT опубликуйте ваше решение как ответ, может будет кому-то полезно.